# Animate bg color with hsb model Java

Tags: java, swing, awt, thread-sleep, setbackground

I'm fairly new to java, so i don't think I have this fairly close to right, but I can seem to find any other help with this. Basically, I'm trying to animate a jPanel's background color so that it's hue (I'm using an hsb color model) changes. sort of like this: https://kahoot.it/#/  notice how the color kinda floats from one to another. Here is my code that I have so far:

```
public void animate(){


    for(float i=.001f;i<1f;i+=.001f){


            jPanel1.setBackground(Color.getHSBColor(i, .53f, .97f));
            try{
                Thread.sleep(5L);
            }catch(InterruptedException ex){

            }
        System.out.println(i);

    }

}
```

now i know this probably isn't right, but the loop works fine, the only problem is that the jPanel doesn't "update" until the loop is finished. Sorry all for being a huge noob at stuff like this, and thanks for any responses

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are blocking the event dispatch thread, so no drawing can happen. Use a swing [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead of sleeping. A running example of changing HSB colors:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class ColorCycle {
    private static class ColorPanel extends JPanel {
        private final float stepSize;
        private final Timer timer;
        private int index;

        ColorPanel(final int steps, int fps) {
            stepSize = 1f / steps;
            timer = new Timer(1000 / fps, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    index++;
                    if (index > steps) {
                        index = 0;
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }

        void start() {
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(100, 100);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.getHSBColor(index * stepSize, 1f,  1f));
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Colors");
                ColorPanel panel = new ColorPanel(300, 20);
                frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
                panel.start();  
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Works for me...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class HsbBackground {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new HsbBackground();
    }

    private JPanel jPanel1 = new JPanel();

    public HsbBackground() throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException {

        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
                jFrame.setContentPane(jPanel1);
                jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                jFrame.setSize(400, 300);
                jFrame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        animate();

    }

    public void animate() {

        for (float i = .001f; i < 1f; i += .001f) {

            final float j = i;

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    jPanel1.setBackground(Color.getHSBColor(j, .53f, .97f));
                }
            });

            try {
                Thread.sleep(5L);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

            }
            System.out.println(i);

        }

    }

}
```

Make sure, that you call `setVisible` of your frame before you start your loop.

PS: I updated the code, so that GUI changes are all made from the event dispatching thread. The code still works fine.

Comment: -1, it works for you because you are not creating your GUI correctly. The GUI should be created on the Event Dispatch Thread. If you were doing this then the Thread.sleep() would cause the GUI to freeze until only the last color is displayed so you would not see the animation. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency[(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information.

Comment: I found a solution to avoid that kind of problem, by splitting my code into two steps: The first one tells the GUI to update (in event dispatching thread) and the second steps sleeps 5 millis. (see my updated code for the solution)

Comment: Nevertheless, kiheru's Timer seems to be the better option. Didn't know, that the Timer actually processes in the AWT-Event queue. :)

Comment: @slartidan Just an aside: There's a difference between `java.util.Timer` and `javax.swing.Timer` : Only the latter works on the EDT